# Why do we ignore the main effects when the interactions are not significant in a three-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, spss, t-test, interaction, experiment-design

I'm following an SPSS guide online, and the procedure is to first test for a three-way interaction. In my case there was **no sig. three-way interaction**. Then the procedure asks me to consider two-way interactions. However, the guide says **if I do not have any sig. two-way interactions, then I can stop** the analysis there. Why? How come I don't consider the main effects of each factor individually? In a two-way ANOVA, you consider both the interactions and the main effects.

Answer (score 4):

Either you are misreading the guide or the guide is wrong. What you are saying makes no sense. Can you post a link to the guide or give an exact quote of the passage?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense. That's why I'm asking. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/Q3w6i.

Comment: That looks like someone made a typo. Or maybe it's just an error.